# Objeto da listview para cada ManActivity

Tags: android, listview

Gostaria de chamar uma Manactivity para cada objeto da listview, sem passar nada para a nova pois vou criar o conteudo das Manactivitys separados.Porem como esta o codigo abaixa, qualquer item que eu click, chama a mesma Manactivity. Quero chamar Manactivity1, 2 e tc por cada objeto.
package com.example.listview;

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvEscolas);
        final ArrayList <Escola> escolas = adicionarEscolas();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new EscolaAdapter(this, escolas);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);    

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {    
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

                //intent.putExtra("nome", escolas.get(i).getNome());

                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Para seu problema eis a solução.

```
   //modelo 1
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Escola escola = (Escola) adapter.getItem(i);

            Intent intent;

            switch (escola.getId()) {
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MinhaAtividadeA.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MinhaAtividadeB.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MinhaAtividadeDefault.class);
                    break;
            }

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

Você pode usar o switch para pegar pelo identificador único se os dados forem fixos, ou você pode utilizar outras formas de validação para iniciar as tela individualmente.

Ou você pode ser mais ousado e por uma activity dentro do próprio objeto escola

```
//modelo 2
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Escola escola = (Escola) adapter.getItem(i);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, escola.getClasse());

            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    });
```

Na classe escola

```
public class Escola {
    private Class classe;

public Class getClasse() {
    return classe;
}

public void setClasse(Class classe) {
    this.classe = classe;
}
```